# Dynamically created form successfully routes to controller but not posting AJAX data

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

When a new product form is loaded in to the user's screen, everything loads in successfully in regards to HTML,CSS and event broadcasting etc. However when a user clicks 'buy now' on this dynamically added product I get an error in the UserController function that it posts to. It's as if the data isn't even being sent at all.

Here is my event listener on client side where form is added

```
var productToAdd="<div class='product' id='" + newProductData.id + "'>" +
                    "<div class='product-image'><img id='image' src='/imgs/products/" + newProductData.type + ".png'></div>" +
                    "<div class='product-content'>" +
                    "<div class='product-title' id='product-title'>" + newProductData.title.toUpperCase() + "</div>" +
                    "<div class='product-price'>PRICE PER UNIT: " +
                    "<div class='price-value' id='price'>" + newProductData.price + "</div>" +
                    " EXENS</div>" +
                    "<br/>" +
                    "QUANTITY: <div class='quantity-value' id='quantity'>" + newProductData.quantity + "</div>" +
                    "<br/>" +
                    "SELLER: <div class='seller' id='seller'>" + newProductData.seller + "</div>" +
                    "<br/>" +
                    "PRICE: <div class='total-price' id='total-price'>" + newProductData.price * newProductData.quantity + "</div>" +
                    "<br/>" +
                    "<form class='buy-product-form' action='/UoE/buy-product/" + newProductData.id + "' method='POST'>"  +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='_token' value='" + add_csrf + "'>" +
                    "<button class='pull-right btn btn-primary'>BUY NOW</button>" +
                    "</form>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>";

                $('.content').append(productToAdd);
```

Here is the AJAX function when the button gets pressed. Note that this works for every product that is loaded in when the page loads

```
$('form.buy-product-form').on('submit', (function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var product_id = $(this).closest('.product').attr("id");
                var element = $(this).closest('.product');
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'id': product_id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data.valid_funds) {
                            updateSideBarContent(data.player_capital, data.total_price, data.player_utility,
                                data.marginal_utility, data.purchases);
                        }else {
                            window.alert("You do not have enough funds!");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                            window.alert("Error, product may no longer exist. Transaction cancelled!");
                            $(element).css('background-color', 'red');
                            $(element).fadeout("100", removeElement(element));
                    }
                });
            }));
```

I get a user controller error

```
ErrorException in UserController.php line 279:
Trying to get property 'quantity_available' of non-object
```

Here is my user controller code

```
public function buyProduct(Request $request){
        $product_id = $request->id;
        $player = Player::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $product = Product::where('id', $product_id)->first();

        $totalPrice = $product->quantity_available * $product->price;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the data is being posted. Because I assign an $id variable to the request->id that is being posted and this usually works fine for products that are loaded in when the page loads in too.

Comment: Edit the question and add your UserController function code

Comment: I've just added the user controller code

Comment: Can you inspect the element and check that `newProductData.id` is actually a number?

Comment: Yes I have used Pusher's debug console and it is a valid number. As well as console.log();

Comment: Can you grab that number and hardcode it in your controller instead of `$request->id` to see if you actually have that record in database?